# Column headers like pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find out the mix of member grades that visit my stores.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'MbrID':['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7']
                    ,'Store':['PAR','TPM','AMK','TPM','PAR','PAR','AMK']
                    ,'Grade':['A','A','B','A','C','A','C']})
df=df[['MbrID','Store','Grade']]
print(df)

df.groupby('Store').agg({'Grade':pd.Series.nunique})
```

Below is the dataframe and also the result of groupby function.

[image]

How do I produce the result like Excel Pivot table, such that the categories of Grade (A,B,C) is the column headers? This is assuming that I have quite a wide range of member grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshaping by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Store','Grade'])['Grade'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Grade  A  B  C
Store         
AMK    0  1  1
PAR    2  0  1
TPM    2  0  0
```

Solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Store, df.Grade)
print (df2)
Grade  A  B  C
Store         
AMK    0  1  1
PAR    2  0  1
TPM    2  0  0
```

and with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df3 = df.pivot_table(index='Store', 
                     columns='Grade', 
                     values='MbrID', 
                     aggfunc=len,
                     fill_value=0)
print (df3)
Grade  A  B  C
Store         
AMK    0  1  1
PAR    2  0  1
TPM    2  0  0
```

Comment: I am not sure if understand your question, can you add desired output if it is something else if my outputs? thank you.

Comment: actually only stores and grade columns are needed. mbr ID column is just for better understanding. the desire output is store code as index, mbr grade as column header, and values is the count of grades in each store

Comment: exactly, pnly a bit slowier as first solution. Thank you for accepting!